# JS / JSON: Cannot redirect to next page after insert data (AJAX JSON)

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

Based on my question, I have successfully added input data to the database using ajax. However, it cannot redirect to the next page, "viewDetails.html" after inserting the data. Can anyone know how to fix it?

```
<script>

    $('#userForm').submit(function(e){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://yes.hus.com/yesss/husss.asmx/TGA_AppAttendanceInsert?",
            data:$('#userForm').serialize(),
            

            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log("Pending to send");
            },

            success: function(response){
                console.log("Pending to send" + response);
                window.location.href = "viewDetails.html";
                return true;
            },
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Assuming the ajax request is successful, I don't see any reason for this code not to work

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.preventDefault()` after submit function line.

Like

```
<script>
    $('#userForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://yes.hus.com/yesss/husss.asmx/TGA_AppAttendanceInsert?",
            data:$('#userForm').serialize(),
            

            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log("Pending to send");
            },

            success: function(response){
                console.log("Pending to send" + response);
                window.location.href = "viewDetails.html";
                return true;
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

When you use `element.submit` function, javascript will automatically send request to server side. So usually you don't need an ajax function inside it. Except you need to do something after request.

With `e.preventDefault()`, submit default function will stop and go to your ajax function.

Also you don't need a question marks on url. Ajax will generate it automatically.